# How i can make it work my filter on a .map with react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, filter

I'm trying to filer my array on my .map but my filter doesn't seems working.

```
let choixLigue = this.state.sport.clubs.filter( async function (choix)  { choix.ligue == "UEFA EURO"}  ).map((choix)=> {
return 
    })
      
      
    console.log (choixLigue)
   
  };
```

When i filter with UEFA EURO , i still have all y object (ligue 1 + UEFA) on my console log .

Did i forget something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter function does not return a value and why do you make the filter async?

Then also your map-function does not return a value but just return.

```
let choixLigue = this.state.sport.clubs.filter((choix)  {  
  return choix.ligue == "UEFA EURO"
}).map((choix)=> {
  return choix.ligue;
})
console.log (choixLigue)
```

Comment: thank you @christian is working, i added the async because i tried to put an async storage before